# Image segmentation: identify spots and scratches with irregular borders

Tags: computer-vision, pattern-matching, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation

A quick introduction: I do physics research which includes experimental measurements and numerical simulations.
Below is the image which is the result of our theoretical model

[image: Numerical Simulation].

Without going into details, I just say that the intensity and color here represent a simulated physical quantity.

Experimental results  are below

[image: Experimental]

The measurement has more features and details but it also has a lot of "invalid" data which are represented by darker spots, scratches and marks which have irregular borders and can vary in size and shape. Nonetheless by comparing these two pictures we can visually identify "invalid" pixels on the second figure which is the problem I am trying to solve using a computer.
Simple thresholding by intensity won't work because the valid data also can vary in intensity. I was thinking about using CNN but then I realized that it would be very tedious to prepare a training dataset because there a lot of small marks/spots needs to be marked and manually marking them will take a lot of time.
Is there any other solution for this problem? Or may be there is a pretrained neural network ( maybe SVM?) which handles a similar problem?

Comment: Would it help to subtract the two images and analyse regions where the two images differ from each other?

Answer (score 0):

Let's check all options one by one taking into account the following:

1. you have a very specific physical process
2. you need accurate results
   (both process-wise and geometry-wise)

**CNNs**

It will be hard to find a "ready-to-be-used" model for your specific process. Moreover, there will be a need to take some specific actions to get an accurate geometry out of it:

[image]

https://ai.facebook.com/blog/using-a-classical-rendering-technique-to-push-state-of-the-art-for-image-segmentation/

**Background subtraction**

Background subtraction will require a threshold, so for your examples and conditions it has no sense. I produced two masks based on subtracted background, find the difference:

[image]

[image]

**Color-based segmentation**

With a properly defined threshold (let's assume we use delta_E) you can segment several areas of interest. For example, lets define three:

- bright red
- red
- black/dark red

Let's compare:

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Additional area:

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

So color-based segmentation seems to be an option, but it is better to improve input if possible. I hope it makes any sense.